# PHP Regex : several stopping characters with Positive lookbehind

Tags: php, regex, lookbehind

Hi stackoverflow community !
I'm trying to use a simple regex expression in PHP based on a *Positive lookbehind*. My objective is to extract everything in a URL between a domain name and a set of specific characters (? or & or /). I want to extract "bar" on those examples :

- `foo.com/bar?`
- `foo.com/bar&`
- `foo.com/bar/`

I tried

```
(?<=foo\.com\/)[^/?&]+
```

it works fine in [the plateform test](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)
but not with PHP 5.3x preg_match : the error thrown is that I can't use several stopping characters -  it works with one.

I also tried a combination of positive lookbehind/lookahead, but the issue remains the same.
What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Did you enclose the regex inside delimiters? Could you show us your code?

Comment: @M42 sure ! Here it is : `preg_match("/(?<=foo\.com\/)[^/?&]+/", "http://www.foo.com/bar?", $result);`

Comment: You need to escape all the slashes: `/(?<=foo\.com\/)[^\/?&]+/` including the one in the character class.

Comment: ho ! thank you for you reactivity Mister 42 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, unlike (say) JavaScript, you can't use the regex-delimiter without escaping it, *even inside a character class*. So, you need to change this:

```
"/(?<=foo\.com\/)[^/?&]+/"
```

to this:

```
"/(?<=foo\.com\/)[^\/?&]+/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the slashes:

```
preg_match("/(?<=foo\.com\/)[^\/?&]+/", "http://www.foo.com/bar?", $result);
                      here ___^
```

or use another delimiter

```
preg_match("#(?<=foo\.com/)[^/?&]+#", "http://www.foo.com/bar?", $result);
```